# running Windows application on linux with DotNetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have created a C# project in visual studio 19 as platform target -Linux, framework- .Netcore 3.1. when I try to publish this project with following settings Target Framework- netcorapp3.1 Deployment Mode- self contained Target Runtime - linux-x64 now when i try to publish this project , I m getting as error

"Publish has encountered an error. Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location: "C:\User........\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3ECA.tmp""

"There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'linux-x64'. "___________________________________________________________________

how to resolve this error ? I Want to develop project on visual stidio19 to run its exe on Linux.

Comment: It's called **Windows** Forms for a reason.

Comment: You need to think about this critically for a second. If you can run a windows application on *not windows*, technically its not a windows application no? However, a windows form application needs to be run on windows `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` Lets see if you can map together the problem here

Comment: check out [maui]

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's really the time to move people away from Mono. WinForms has been partial supported and broken in many spots on Mono, and GTK# needs a lot of updates. And .NET Core ships with GUI frameworks since 1.0 (ASP.NET Core), and desktop GUI (WinForms/WPF) since 3.1, and cross platform GUI in upcoming 6.0 (MAUI), so no need to mention Mono as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms is an application framework designed for the Windows operating system. While you can technically compile and run it under linux using mono, it would be advisable to look for cross-platform or even linux-native UI framework to use, if you intend on targeting Linux as a platform.